# Can you please tell me the logic/purpose of the CSS codes below?

Tags: css, tags, webkit, google-tag-manager, margins

I would appreciate a lot if you could help me understand the purpose/logic behind the CSS snippets below:

1. **Code N1**

```css
@media not all and (min-resolution: 0.001dpcm) and (max-device-width: 768px) {
  @supports (-webkit-appearance:none) and (stroke-color:transparent) {
    .friendbuy {
      margin-top: auto !important;
      margin-bottom: auto !important;
      margin-left: auto !important;
      margin-right: auto !important;
    }
  }
}
```

2. **Code N2**

```css
@media not all and (min-resolution: 0.001dpcm) and (max-device-width: 768px) {
  @supports (-webkit-appearance:none) and (stroke-color:transparent) {
    a.friendbuycta {
      margin-left: 0px !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What Javascript?

Comment: First of all, this is not a Js snippet, this is CSS. Both are doing a similar thing. You might just read the line and it already makes sense. If the device has a certain resolution and a maximal width, then check if certain css properties are supported by the browser and if so, set a certain styling for an element.

Comment: The purpose I cannot say anything about, as it is somehow related to your application, I guess. Seems like someone tries to reset styles on mobile devices.

Comment: Also I recommend, if you work as Frontend developer, to learn the basics of the craft ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can read that code as a long `IF`-statement:

```
IF @media not all
   and (min-resolution: 0.001dpcm)
   and (max-device-width: 768px) 

THEN {
   IF @supports (-webkit-appearance:none)
                and (stroke-color:transparent) 

   THEN {
      .friendbuy =  {
         margin-top   : auto !important;
         margin-bottom: auto !important;
         margin-left  : auto !important;
         margin-right : auto !important;
      }
   }
}
```

The rest is CSS 101. Now you do the second one...